bad address when I use copy_to_user() in Loadable kernel module
When I am programming a loadable kernel module in Linux, I added a system call that traverses processes and stores them in a structure, then uses copy_to_user() to copy the structure from kernel space to user space. However, I encountered an error during the copy_to_user() process.
this is my struct:
struct process
{
    int pid;
    int depth;
    int have_brother;
    char name[16]; 
}

Below is my module code.
#define free_syscall_num    336             //free syscall number
#define syscall_table_address 0xffffffff8d200320    //syscall table address

long(*save_syscall)(void);                  //Save the original sys_ni_syscall();
unsigned long *syscall_table=0;             

struct process a[1000];         
int counter = 0;    

/*
*Recursively traverse the linux process tree
*/
void preorder_traversal_processtree(struct task_struct *p_task,int b)
{
    struct list_head *list;
        
    a[counter].pid = p_task -> pid;
    a[counter].depth = b;
    if(p_task -> sibling.next == &(p_task->parent->children))   
        {
            a[counter].have_brother=0;
        }
    else
        {
            a[counter].have_brother=1;
        }
    
    strcpy(a[counter].name,p_task -> comm);                     
    printk("pid: %d\n", a[counter].pid);
    counter ++;

    list_for_each(list, &p_task->children)                      
    {
        printk("pstree is running, counter = %d\n", counter);
        struct task_struct *t = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling); 
        preorder_traversal_processtree(t,b+1);                                  
    }
    
}

/*
The body of the system call
*/
asmlinkage long my_syscall(char __user* buf)
{
    counter = 0;
    preorder_traversal_processtree(&init_task,0);                           
    if (!access_ok(buf, 1000 * sizeof(struct process))) 
    {
        printk("Invalid user space address\n");
    }

    if(copy_to_user((struct process *)buf, a, 1000*sizeof(struct process)))
    {
        printk("Efault\n");
        return -EFAULT;
        
    }
    else
    {
        printk("%lu\n",sizeof(a));
        return sizeof(a);
    }
}


module_init(mymod_init);    
module_exit(mymod_exit);    
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");


this is my test code:
 
struct process a[1000];
int brother_reg[100]; 

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int x = syscall(336, &a);   
    
    printf("%d\n",a[0].pid); 
    return 0;
}



I tried testing with access_ok() and found that the address is invalid. When I tested with strace, syscall_0x150() returned -1 (bad address).Linux is Linux 5.15.0-105-generic.
Any help will great.

A function which pointer is stored in the system call table accepts single argument - const struct pt_regs *regs. Real syscall arguments are stored in registers. And of course, a kernel module shouldn't add a system call. All syscalls are defined in the code which is compiled directly to the kernel. Kernel modules should use other mechanisms for interact with user space.

Thank you for your answer！Now I know the function only accept one pointer argument  since kernel version 4.17. I have solved the bad address！

You are creating a large array in global space with the name a.  You should be using a local variable and kmalloc/kfree.
